# #parent>*/asterisk vs. #parent>div

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Using the child selector to match *any* child, which happens to always be a div, would it be faster to use the `*`/asterisk selector or simply `div`? Because it is both always a div and a child, neither selector is more suitable other than performance-wise.

**HTML** (obviously more than two)

```
<div id="parent">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#parent>* {
    padding: 2px 1em;
    }

#parent>div {
    padding: 2px 1em;
    }
```

Forgive me if it's been asked and answered, it's hard to search for a wildcard character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS selectors are evaluated right-to-left.**

So with `#parent > *` the browser would have to check whether the rest of the selector matches for *every* element on the page, no matter where in the DOM tree it is located;

whereas with `#parent > div` the browser can stop this process as soon as he determines that the element for which it is currently trying to determine whether or not the selector applies is *not* a `div` element.

So yes, `#parent > div` is totally preferable performance-wise in this situation.

Comment: I'd imagine `#parent>*` would check until an element is the child of #parent, whereas `#parent>div` would check until an element is div, and then check again whether that div is a child of #parent.

Comment: The check for whether any element’s tagname matches `*` or `div` is done first, and only if that yields true, the DOM tree will be traversed further up to see whether that element has an ancestor with the id `parent`.

Comment: Wouldn't `*` skip tag name checking since it doesn't apply?

Comment: Well since `*` means “any tag name” you could say this does not require an actual “check” – but this is not the issue here when you want to discuss the performance of those two selectors; what happens _after_ is.

Comment: I'm still confused. I see it as `*` taking all elements, then checking if they belong to a parent; whereas `div` takes all elements, then checks if they are a div, then takes *those* elements and checks if they belong to a parent, thus taking twice as many steps. I could picture the parent check itself being slower, however, if that would be the cause.

Comment: _“the DOM tree will be traversed further up to see whether that element has an ancestor with the id parent”_ – small correction here, since `>` is used between the two parts, “ancestor” should of course have been _parent_ here instead; but that does not change the rest of the situation.

Comment: _All_ elements are “taken” as a first step in _any_ case – the browser has to check for each and every element, whether any given CSS selector applies to it. So _all_ elements in the DOM are checked for whether they match `*` or `div` first of all – and only after that it is checked whether or not their parent element matches `#parent` or not. However, for any element that is _not_ a `div`, this second step does not have to be undertaken in the first place – whereas with `*`, it does have to be done for _every_ element.

Comment: If you had three elements on your page, with tag names `div`, `foo` and `bar` – then `#parent > *` means for _all three_ of those the check _“does the parent of this element have the id `parent`?”_ has to be performed – whereas with `#parent > div` this check only has to be performed for the _one_ element with tag name `div`.